# SQL to consider duplicates while using minus operation

Tags: sql, sql-server

Scenario is with the below tables with two column values separated by hyphen

Table1

```
Kavana-01
Sandhya-01
Sandhya-02
```

ExceptionTable

```
Kavana-01
Sandhya-01
```

Outputtable

```
Kavana-01
Sandhya-02
```

Requirement is to get the output like in outputttable = Table1 Minus ExceptionTable considering the uniqueness in Table1. Since the word Kavana is unique, it should not be considered for the minus operation.

Comment: What is "two column values separated by hyphen"? What "considering the uniqueness" means? All values in your table seem to be unique, so you must mean something else.

Comment: With "minus operation", you mean [`EXCEPT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2018)?

Comment: Wouldn't Table 1 'minus' ExceptionTable would return only Sandhya-02?

Comment: Sandhya-02 --> this is single column value or its from multiple columns.  Providing clear table structure will help everyone here to provide expected answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this. assume col1 and col2 is the first column and second column**

```
    SELECT t.col1,t.col2,e1.col2 AS prio FROM 
(SELECT t1.col1,t1.col2, row_number() over (partition by t1.col1 order by CASE WHEN e1.col2 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) 
as OrderNumber
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN ExceptionTable e1 ON t1.col1=e1.col1 AND t1.col2=e1.col2) t
WHERE t.prio IS NULL OR t.OrderNumber=1
```

My test code. I am using the temp table here

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1 (
    col1 varchar(255),
    col2 varchar(255)
);


CREATE TABLE #ExceptionTable (
    col1 varchar(255),
    col2 varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO #Table1 (col1,col2) values ('Kavana','01');
INSERT INTO #Table1 (col1,col2) values ('Sandhya','01');
INSERT INTO #Table1 (col1,col2) values ('Sandhya','02');
INSERT INTO #Table1 (col1,col2) values ('Mounil','01');
INSERT INTO #Table1 (col1,col2) values ('Mounil','02');

INSERT INTO #ExceptionTable (col1,col2) values ('Kavana','01');
INSERT INTO #ExceptionTable (col1,col2) values ('Sandhya','01');

--DROP TABLE #Table1
--DROP TABLE #ExceptionTable

SELECT * FROM #Table1
SELECT * FROM #ExceptionTable

SELECT t.col1,t.col2 FROM 
(SELECT t1.col1,t1.col2,e1.col2 AS prio, row_number() over (partition by t1.col1 order by CASE WHEN e1.col2 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) 
as OrderNumber
FROM #Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN #ExceptionTable e1 ON t1.col1=e1.col1 AND t1.col2=e1.col2) t
WHERE t.prio IS NULL OR t.OrderNumber=1
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment ,but the above query results with wrong output ---Sandhya-01
Sandhya-02

Comment: Are you sure? I got the correct answer. please check any typo mistack
Kavana-01
Sandhya-02

Comment: Thanks a lot,but still its not correct because addition of two more columns--

INSERT INTO #Table1 (col1,col2) values ('Mounil','01');
INSERT INTO #Table1 (col1,col2) values ('Mounil','02');

Will result in only one row.Ideally it should be two rows as  Mounil is not present in Exeption table

Comment: @kavana you are right. I update my query now check it. If you have any other scenario, please post it.

Answer (score 0):

One method in SQL Server is `except`:

```
select col1, col2
from table1
except
select col1, col2
from table2;
```